# Do you have to select both Flier and Fast Movement if you have a Raven Familiar?

Tags: familiars, pathfinder-2e

On the page [Familiars](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx) it says, "If your familiar is an animal that naturally has one of these abilities (for instance, an owl has a fly Speed), you must select that ability. Your familiar can’t be an animal that naturally has more familiar abilities than your daily maximum familiar abilities."

Also, within the [Raven](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=781) stat block  "Speed 10 feet, fly 40 feet"

Lastly, On the [Familiars](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx) mentioned above, "Fast Movement (Core Rulebook pg. 218 2.0): Increase one of the familiar’s Speeds from 25 feet to 40 feet.
Flier (Core Rulebook pg. 218 2.0): It gains a fly Speed of 25 feet."

**Therefore, do you have to select both flier and Fast Movement automatically each morning as a result of a Raven having a natural flight speed of 40 feet?**

*side note* I find it extremely infuriating that they give an example of an owl, when by RAW, you cannot select an Owl. You must select an animal that is classified as tiny, and owls fall into the category of Bird, which is Small, not tiny [Bird : Eagle, Hawk, Owl](https://2e.aonprd.com/AnimalCompanions.aspx?ID=3)

Much appreciated for your time, consideration, and grace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Familiars gain no abilities from the kind of animal they are, and must instead take the abilities. The only things they gain directly from the kind of animal you choose are the thematic description and appearance.

If you are taking a Raven, you must select Flier if you want your Raven to fly at all. It will gain a fly speed of 25 feet.

If you then take Fast Movement, you will be able to increase it's flight speed to 40 feet.

RAW it could easily be argued that you must take Flier and Fast Movement, but I personally wouldn't enforce that.

As a GM, I would simply rule it that you only have the abilities you select, and allow you to select them as you like -- for example, you could select a wingless Raven, and thus not have to take Flier.

Comment: Awesome. That is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I also appreciate your interpretation on how to rule it if you were the GM, I think that is a sensible decision as well. Thank you very much for the insight!

Comment: Only Evil witches clip wings =P JK, fluff should be up to the player. On a more serious note, I'd recommend rewording the start of this answer. The question is "Do you **have to select both Flier and Fast Movement**..." based on non-familiar ravens having 40ft fly speed; you open with "**Yes.** Familiars gain no abilities..." but later clarify, with no emphasis "If you are taking a Raven, you must select Flier [...] If you then take Fast Movement..." indicating that it's not required to take both (it's not).

Comment: @Ifusaso is Fast Movement not required? (not quite sure what your final two words are saying 'not' to) The normal Raven has the ability 40 foot flight, and that is an ability in the list. I agree it's not anywhere near as crystal clear cut as flight, but that's why I said 'it could easily be argued that...'.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I don't believe Fast Movement is required because nothing about normal Ravens say they have "Fast Movement" just a fly speed that happens to be faster than a typical familiar. I agree it could be argued, but by that argument, their example of an owl doesn't work because there is no creature statted out as an owl; they also don't say an owl needs Fast Movement and I can almost *guarantee* you that if they do get statted out, they won't have a 25ft fly.

Comment: I appreciate this discussion on the topic. That's EXACTLY where I was confused. I would absolutely love it if someone made a list of all the possible RAW familiars they can choose and EXACTLY which familiar abilities they are required to commit to as a result of that choice. Very much like the Specific Familiars that specify how many abilities the PC must commit to that Familiar. . .